# Können Schmähworte mit männlichem Artikel auf Frauen angewendet weren?

Tags: word-usage, gender, insult

Kann ein Schmähwort das grammatikalisch männlich ist auf eine Frau angewendet werden?

Er ist ein Trottel/Depp/Halunke/... => *Sie ist ein Trottel/Depp/Halunke/...* <= ?

Bzw. wie sieht es in der direkten Anrede aus: "Du bist ein Trottel!" - kann das zu einer weiblichen Person gesagt werden?

Comment: Natürlich. Grammatikalisches Geschlecht war schon immer unabhängig von sexuellem Geschlecht, siehe **das Mädchen**, obwoh ein Mädchen generell als weiblich erachtet wird.

Comment: @infinitezero Das liegt in diesem Beispiel aber ausschließlich am verwendeten Diminutiv. Das Jüngchen steht auch im Neutrum. Die Maid hingegen ist feminin.

Comment: @Richard Neumann und Das Mädel?

Comment: Laut Wiktionary _Ableitung des Diminutivums zum Stamm von Magd mit dem Derivatem (Ableitungsmorphem) -el_.

Answer (score 2):

Wie hier schon mehrfach gesagt: Grammatikalisches Geschlecht ist größtenteils unabhängig von sexuellem Geschlecht. Prinzipiell kann so ziemlich jedes Schimpfwort auf beide Geschlechter angewendet werden, mir scheint jedoch, dass Frauen häufiger mit weiblichen Schimpfwörtern beschimpft werden als Männer und umgekehrt. Wahrscheinlich liegt das schlicht daran, dass ein solches Schimpfwort sprachlich naheliegender ist.

Comment: Ich selbst würde "häufiger" auf "weitaus häufiger" steigern -- evtl sogar auf "fast ausschließlich". Das war auch gerade der Grund für die Frage.

Comment: Muss das nicht neuerdings heißen "Sie ist eine Trottel*in.", wenn man nicht wegen Diskriminierung angegangen werden möchte?

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde sagen, wenn es nur ein grammatisches Geschlecht ist, - z.B.: **der Trottel** geht es auf Mann oder Frau. Bei Beschimpfungen die ein reales Geschlecht haben - z.B.: **die Ziege** - geht das nicht so einfach. ob es ein "etabliertes" Schimpfwort - wie **Hornochse** - scheint auch eine Rolle zu spielen.

Wirklich einheitlich ist es aber glaube ich nicht.

Comment: For this I'd very much prefer opinions from F, and accounts of FM, FF, MMF, FFM. In my experience, it's perhaos possible, but very rare, as there are enough stylized slurs. The question is otherwise not limited to slurs; maybe I've just never witnessed a girl being cussed out other than with the typical ones.

Comment: Inwiefern hat Ziege ein reales Geschlecht? Gilt das auch für "Vogel" (schräger Vogel) und die falsche Schlange?

Comment: Die prototypische Ziege ist, wie die anderen wegen Milch gehaltenen Nutztiere, weiblich, würde ich sagen. Heutzutage weniger stark als die Kuh, aber dennoch. Ähnlich auch das Huhn.

Comment: Die Ziege ist sowohl die Bezeichnung der Rasse, als auch des weiblichen Tieres (Umgangssprache)